# Why can't my (auto.)arima-model forecast my time series?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

For testing I generated a very simple time series with a clear recurring pattern. I expected that auto.arima will generate a model, that can forecast that pattern, but óbviously it doesn't. Can anyone give me some hints how I can improve the model in order to predict that pattern correctly?

```
library(forecast)

ts<-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
fit <- auto.arima(ts)
plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
```

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Your data is rather binary than continuous (most time-series models are designed for non-binary data) and 0.7 is a mean of (1,1,1,1,1,0,0), so you got mean forecast...

Comment: yes it just takes the mean, but I expected that the autocorrelation is detected and the pattern is forecasted correctly, what is wrong?

Comment: Check http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77374/what-are-the-assumptions-of-arima-modeling-for-forecasting-time-series your data does not really seems to be ARIMA-friendly: binary, deterministic, with no noise.

Comment: Can you recommend a better approach to forecast that "simple" pattern?

Comment: As @Tim rightly points out your data is deterministic in nature and can be easily modeled using simple rule. If you have five 1s followed by two 0s why do you need to do any modeling? Deterministic series can be modeled simply using linear regression.

Comment: okay maybe that example was to simple, but my goal is more to understand what I can expect from ARIMA when I use it with real data later.
I tried it with another time series as well:

ts<-rep(c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,5,4,3,3,2),10)
ts<-ts*round(runif(length(ts), 0.95, 1.0), digits=2)

Unfortunately I get the mean as well as a forecast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your both examples concern with *deterministic* time series, with *no noise* and no trend. Deterministic time series, with no trend is not really the kind of data that ARIMA was designed for (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77374/what-are-the-assumptions-of-arima-modeling-for-forecasting-time-series) to learn more on ARIMA assumptions).

Actually to forecast future trend given your data what you could do is simply to take averages of different time lags and then repeat them in the same order. The problem in here is to determine the number of lags to use, that is, to find out the length of the window that repeats itself. This could be simply achieved, using sum of squared errors or other error measure. If you define average $k$'th lag value as

$$ \overline x_{(k)} = \frac{1}{N/K} \sum_{i=0}^{(N/K)-1} x_{k+i \times K} $$

and sum of squared errors is

$$ \mathrm{SSE} = \sum_{k=1}^K  \sum_{i=0}^{(N/K)-1} \left( x_{k+i \times K} - \overline x_{(k)} \right)^2 $$

then you can use SSE to choose the best window size. Below you can find an example in R.

```r
tsPattern <- function(x, kmax = ceiling((length(x)/2))) {

  stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
  kmax <- min(round(length(x)/2), kmax)

  predPattern <- function(x, k) {
    n <- length(x)
    pattern <- rep(1:k, times = ceiling(n/k), length.out = n)
    pred <- rep(tapply(x, pattern, mean), times = ceiling(n/k), length.out = n)
    as.numeric(pred)
  }

  out <- NULL
  for (k in 1:kmax) {
    xhat <- predPattern(x, k)
    out[k] <- sum((x - xhat)^2)
  }

  list(fitted = predPattern(x, which.min(out)),
       sumsq = which.min(out))
} 

ts<-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
      1,1,1,1,1)

ts2 <-rep(c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,5,4,3,3,2),10)
ts2 <- ts2 * round(runif(length(ts2), 0.95, 1.0), digits=2)

tsPattern(ts, 10)
tsPattern(ts2, 20)
```

Below you can see the results plotted (red points are estimated values, lines are actual data).

[image]

This primitive approach works very good for your examples of deterministic time series with no trend and no noise, it would fail however with real life data, i.e. exactly in such cases as ARIMA (and other similar time-series methods) were designed for. Below you can see results of using this method and `auto.arima` for real life data (*WWWusage* dataset in [forecast](http://robjhyndman.com/software/forecast/) library).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but you can specify your frequency and tell arima that you have seasonality:

```
library(forecast)

ts<-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)

ts <- ts(ts, frequency = 7)
fit <- auto.arima(ts, D = 1)
plot(forecast(fit,h=20))
```

This works as desired and ARIMA finds the structure.

[image]